# "page not found" due to hat character ("^") in a upload file name

Tags: uploads, characters

I have several uploaded files whose links I have later discovered yield a "page not found" message error, because their name contain the hat character ("^"). Have I to delete and re-upload them after changing their name or is there an option that makes Wordpress to correctly manage their original name?

Comment: I would hardly call that a hat, more like a hand or wing! `^(o.o)^` - Does it include that character in the slug, what does an example slug look like for one of those pages?

Comment: In general, all special characters should be avoided in file names. See [this](http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/web/cms/characters-avoid/)

Comment: This may not have anything to do with WordPress, and WordPress-- even PHP-- may not be able to do anything about it. You are dealing with, potentially, server and filesystem level issues. Your best approach is to change to file names.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee if the filename is x^2.xls the slug is/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/x2.xls

Comment: Files have been uploaded by others, not mine. And they are many. Moreover, I wonder that WordPress allows to upload a file with a potentially problematic character in its name but it is not able to manage it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a filter I use to keep my clients from adding special characters to their filenames, should work for you - you'll have to reupload the file though.

```
/**
 /* Sanitize Uploaded Filenames
 /* @param array $file
 /* @return array $file
 */
function sanitize_file_uploads( $file ){
    $file['name'] = sanitize_file_name($file['name']);
    $file['name'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]/", "", $file['name']);
    $file['name'] = strtolower($file['name']);
    add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'remove_accents');

    return $file;
}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'sanitize_file_uploads');
```

This function only allows numeric, numbers, underscores, dashes, and periods. It converts it to lowercase and also run it through the [accents function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents).